# Changes made to tests outside of Selenium IDE do not appear when opening test suite inside IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm helping train some of our QA team in building Selenium tests and we are using the Selenium IDE. Some IDs were changed on the page, which requires our tests to change to get the correct page elements. I prefer to fix the tests in a text editor because the find-replace functions are much faster than making changes in the IDE.

I'm finding that after making changes to the tests, I can't see the changes in the test suite on the IDE. I've confirmed that the test suite I opened in the IDE is in the same location as the tests I'm opening in my text editor. I can see the changes in the text files. I've also deleted the browser cache (since the IDE runs as part of Firefox). I've deleted the test suite and created a new one from the changed tests (which I can see have changed in the IDE).

How do I get the suite to reflect the changes? What am I missing?

This is with Selenium IDE 1.0.10 on Firefox 3.6.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE appears to cache a snapshot of sorts of the last accessed folder in the filesystem. After navigating farther back up the file hierarchy, then navigating back into the test folder, the changes were evident. It was surprisingly persistent, though.